# Problem with shift in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Tried to use a wrapper around find but hitting the following problem.  I want e.g to provide a few directories as arguments but the last argument is always a number that indicates how old data should be removed. For example:

```
rmoldfiles dir1 dir2 dir3 20
```

This should remove the old files that are older than 30 days `looking at mtime of course`

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

die()
{
  echo >&2 "$@"
  exit 1
}

usage()
{
  echo >&2 "Usage: $0 [dir1 dir2 dir3] [days old]"
  die
}

if [[ (($# < 1)) || -f "$1" ]]; then
  if [[ -f "$1" ]]; then 
    printf '%s\n' "Please provide a directory"
  fi
  usage
fi 

while (( $# )); do 
  while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    printf 'rm %s\n' "$file" 
    sleep 1
  done < <(find "$1" -type f -mtime +$2 -print0)
  shift
done

echo "Done deleting"
```

**Problem**

How to `shift` directories but not the last argument.

Comment: Is there a reason that the number of days needs to be the last argument?  Could you make it the first argument instead? Or could you make it a switch or flag instead of an argument (and use something like `getopt` to parse arguments/switches/flags)?

Comment: @jayhendren I thought about getopts but I wanted not to overcomplicate this so thought just use `"$1" for directories and shift , then use `"$2"` for `-mtime` `

Comment: consider also a simplification of your while find loop: `find "$1" -type f -mtime +"$2" -printf rm '%p\n' -delete` (assuming GNU find, as per the -print0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of solutions.

1. Pick out the last command line argument.

   ```
   args=( "$@" )
   num=${args[-1]}
   args=( "${args[@]:0:${#args[@]} - 1}" )
   ```

   (then use `find "${args[@]}" -type f -mtime "+$num" -print -delete` to delete those files).
2. Put the number first.

   ```
    num=$1; shift
   ```

   (then use `find "$@" -type f -mtime "+$num" -print -delete` to delete the files).

The loop is only needed if you have hundreds or thousands of directories to process, in which case the `find` command would be too long with a single invocation.  Otherwise, don't loop. `find` can take multiple search paths.

If you want to insert a delay and use `rm` explicitly, and have some formatted output for each file:

```
find "$@" -type f -mtime "+$num" -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        printf "Removing %s\n" "$pathname"
        rm -- "$pathname"
        sleep 1
    done' sh {} +
```

If you find that you *do* need to loop over the directories (or if this just feels better):

```
# Assumes that the arguments are in the order
#      num dir1 dir2 dir3 ...

num=$1
shift

for dir do
    printf 'Processing %s...\n' "$dir"

    find "$dir" -type f -mtime "+$num" -exec sh -c '
        for pathname do
            printf "Removing %s\n" "$pathname"
            rm -- "$pathname"
            sleep 1
        done' sh {} +
done
```

or,

```
# Assumes that the arguments are in the order
#      dir1 dir2 dir3 ... num

args=( "$@" )
num=${args[-1]}
args=( "${args[@]:0:${#args[@]} - 1}" )

for dir in "${args[@]}"; do

    # as above

done
```

Comment: Kusalananda where to put this `"+$num"` in your last piece of code?

Comment: @holasz Sorry, the last code snippets assume that you pass the number as the firs argument (because its easiest) and then pick that out into `$num` and `shift` it off. I'll update after my supper.

Comment: Kusalandela ok your last code works when using e.g  `rmoldfiles 27 dir1 dir2 dir3 ...`   Is there a way to use argument as last dir?

Comment: @holasz see first part of answer. I'll update soon.

Comment: @holasz See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Kusalananda. Works nicely! Thanks for providing different ways of passing arguments to the script.

Comment: @holasz The most straight forward would be to have the number _first_ and the varying number of directories after that.  This would make the script more usable. It would, for example, be easy to call _it_ from `find` with `-exec yourscript 20 {} +`, or with `xargs yourscript 20`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're only expecting (and providing) three directories before the age parameter, don't loop indiscriminately; instead, loop explicitly:

```
for dir in 1 2 3; do
  # work with "$1"
  shift
done
```

or stop looping when there's one parameter left:

```
while [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; do
  echo "Work with $1"
  shift;
done
```

Since the "days" parameter moves during each shift, you'll need to save it off initially:

```
days=$4
```

... before calling the loop.

... and if you allow for an arbitrary number of directories to be passed:

```
[ "$#" -gt 1 ] || exit 1
days=${@: -1}
while [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; do
  echo work with "$1" and "$days"
  shift
done
```

This uses the bash array `$@` and asks for the last element of it (indicated by `-1`, separated by a space to prevent it from being interpreted as a modifier to `:`); it then loops over the parameters one by one until there's one left (the initial 'day' parameter at the end).

Answer (score 1):

Just change `(( $# ))` to `(( $# > 1))`:

```
while (( $# > 1 )); do
  echo "file is: $1"
done

echo "days are: $1"
```